Broken vertical alignment with eps and eps_tex
Also posted on reddit.
I am trying to add an exported figure from Inkscape to my latex files. However, the vertical alignment of the text and objects in the figure seems to be broken.
Here is the document:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\input{test.eps_tex}}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

test.eps_tex is the file exported from inkscape. It is derived from this 14x3cm svg (not to scale):

However, the rendered figure looks like this:

Clearly, the vertical alignment is incorrect and there is a large whitespace between the text and the rectangle.
To reproduce this, take the following svg:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
width="14cm"
height="3cm"
viewBox="0 0 139.99999 30"
version="1.1"
id="svg1"
inkscape:version="1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25)"
sodipodi:docname="test.svg"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<sodipodi:namedview
    id="namedview1"
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#000000"
    borderopacity="0.25"
    inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
    inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    inkscape:zoom="1.8958319"
    inkscape:cx="122.37372"
    inkscape:cy="77.538521"
    inkscape:window-width="1392"
    inkscape:window-height="1027"
    inkscape:window-x="1998"
    inkscape:window-y="25"
    inkscape:window-maximized="0"
    inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
<defs
    id="defs1" />
<g
    inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1">
    <path
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    d="M 3.9473682,15 H 130.65789"
    id="path1" />
    <rect
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.289175;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    id="rect1"
    width="14.578605"
    height="4.9489274"
    x="11.41181"
    y="6.7481618" />
    <text
    xml:space="preserve"
    style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.88056px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    x="18.701111"
    y="3.5731616"
    id="text1"><tspan
        sodipodi:role="line"
        id="tspan1"
        style="stroke-width:0.353483;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal;font-size:3.88055993px;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;stroke:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1"
        x="18.701111"
        y="3.5731616">Test text</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>

in inkscape and export it as .eps, with separate text in a .eps_tex file.
The resulting .eps is:
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.18.0 (https://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Fri Sep 13 12:52:30 2024
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 11 42 371 68
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
/Q { grestore } bind def
/cm { 6 array astore concat } bind def
/w { setlinewidth } bind def
/J { setlinecap } bind def
/j { setlinejoin } bind def
/M { setmiterlimit } bind def
/d { setdash } bind def
/m { moveto } bind def
/l { lineto } bind def
/c { curveto } bind def
/h { closepath } bind def
/re { exch dup neg 3 1 roll 5 3 roll moveto 0 rlineto
    0 exch rlineto 0 rlineto closepath } bind def
/S { stroke } bind def
/f { fill } bind def
/f* { eofill } bind def
/n { newpath } bind def
/W { clip } bind def
/W* { eoclip } bind def
/BT { } bind def
/ET { } bind def
/BDC { mark 3 1 roll /BDC pdfmark } bind def
/EMC { mark /EMC pdfmark } bind def
/cairo_store_point { /cairo_point_y exch def /cairo_point_x exch def } def
/Tj { show currentpoint cairo_store_point } bind def
/TJ {
{
dup
type /stringtype eq
{ show } { -0.001 mul 0 cairo_font_matrix dtransform rmoveto } ifelse
} forall
currentpoint cairo_store_point
} bind def
/cairo_selectfont { cairo_font_matrix aload pop pop pop 0 0 6 array astore
cairo_font exch selectfont cairo_point_x cairo_point_y moveto } bind def
/Tf { pop /cairo_font exch def /cairo_font_matrix where
    { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Td { matrix translate cairo_font_matrix matrix concatmatrix dup
    /cairo_font_matrix exch def dup 4 get exch 5 get cairo_store_point
    /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Tm { 2 copy 8 2 roll 6 array astore /cairo_font_matrix exch def
    cairo_store_point /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/g { setgray } bind def
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
/d1 { setcachedevice } bind def
/cairo_data_source {
CairoDataIndex CairoData length lt
{ CairoData CairoDataIndex get /CairoDataIndex CairoDataIndex 1 add def }
{ () } ifelse
} def
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 11 42 371 68
%%EndPageSetup
q 11 42 360 26 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 86 cm q
0 g
1.001999 w
0 J
0 j
[] 0.0 d
4 M q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
11.188 42.52 m 370.367 42.52 l S Q
0.819709 w
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
32.348 19.129 41.324 14.027 re S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end
%%EOF

And the .eps_tex is:
%% Creator: Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25), www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'test.eps' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
}%
\providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
}%
\providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
\newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
\newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
\ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{396.8503937bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
    \relax%
    \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
\else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
\fi%
\global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
\global\let\svgscale\undefined%
\makeatother%
\begin{picture}(1,0.21428571)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{test.eps}}%
    \put(0.13357937,0.18876313){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%

Edit 1
This seemst to be somewhat related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/380501
Edit 2
The answer of @cabohah provides a partial solution for the images as above. But then I came across another example, where exporting the drawing does not work.
The new svg is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
width="14cm"
height="3cm"
viewBox="0 0 139.99999 30"
version="1.1"
id="svg1"
inkscape:version="1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25)"
sodipodi:docname="test2.svg"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<sodipodi:namedview
    id="namedview1"
    pagecolor="#000000"
    bordercolor="#000000"
    borderopacity="0.04313725"
    inkscape:showpageshadow="true"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pagecheckerboard="true"
    inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    inkscape:zoom="1.8958319"
    inkscape:cx="299.07715"
    inkscape:cy="35.340686"
    inkscape:window-width="1920"
    inkscape:window-height="1027"
    inkscape:window-x="1470"
    inkscape:window-y="25"
    inkscape:window-maximized="1"
    inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
    showborder="true"
    borderlayer="true"
    shape-rendering="auto" />
<defs
    id="defs1" />
<g
    inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1">
    <path
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    d="M 3.9473682,15 H 130.65789"
    id="path1" />
    <rect
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.289175;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    id="rect1"
    width="14.578605"
    height="4.9489274"
    x="11.41181"
    y="6.7481618" />
    <text
    xml:space="preserve"
    style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.88056px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    x="18.701111"
    y="3.5731616"
    id="text1"><tspan
        sodipodi:role="line"
        id="tspan1"
        style="stroke-width:0.353483;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal;font-size:3.88055993px;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;stroke:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1"
        x="18.701111"
        y="3.5731616">Test text</tspan></text>
    <text
    xml:space="preserve"
    style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.88056px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    x="127.24631"
    y="26.944984"
    id="text1-9"><tspan
        sodipodi:role="line"
        id="tspan1-6"
        style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.88056px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.353483"
        x="127.24631"
        y="26.944984">Test text</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>

resulting in this .eps file
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.18.0 (https://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Fri Sep 13 22:20:12 2024
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 34 360 59
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
/Q { grestore } bind def
/cm { 6 array astore concat } bind def
/w { setlinewidth } bind def
/J { setlinecap } bind def
/j { setlinejoin } bind def
/M { setmiterlimit } bind def
/d { setdash } bind def
/m { moveto } bind def
/l { lineto } bind def
/c { curveto } bind def
/h { closepath } bind def
/re { exch dup neg 3 1 roll 5 3 roll moveto 0 rlineto
    0 exch rlineto 0 rlineto closepath } bind def
/S { stroke } bind def
/f { fill } bind def
/f* { eofill } bind def
/n { newpath } bind def
/W { clip } bind def
/W* { eoclip } bind def
/BT { } bind def
/ET { } bind def
/BDC { mark 3 1 roll /BDC pdfmark } bind def
/EMC { mark /EMC pdfmark } bind def
/cairo_store_point { /cairo_point_y exch def /cairo_point_x exch def } def
/Tj { show currentpoint cairo_store_point } bind def
/TJ {
{
    dup
    type /stringtype eq
    { show } { -0.001 mul 0 cairo_font_matrix dtransform rmoveto } ifelse
} forall
currentpoint cairo_store_point
} bind def
/cairo_selectfont { cairo_font_matrix aload pop pop pop 0 0 6 array astore
    cairo_font exch selectfont cairo_point_x cairo_point_y moveto } bind def
/Tf { pop /cairo_font exch def /cairo_font_matrix where
    { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Td { matrix translate cairo_font_matrix matrix concatmatrix dup
    /cairo_font_matrix exch def dup 4 get exch 5 get cairo_store_point
    /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Tm { 2 copy 8 2 roll 6 array astore /cairo_font_matrix exch def
    cairo_store_point /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/g { setgray } bind def
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
/d1 { setcachedevice } bind def
/cairo_data_source {
CairoDataIndex CairoData length lt
    { CairoData CairoDataIndex get /CairoDataIndex CairoDataIndex 1 add def }
    { () } ifelse
} def
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 34 360 59
%%EndPageSetup
q 0 34 360 25 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 75 cm q
0 g
1.001999 w
0 J
0 j
[] 0.0 d
4 M q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
0 40.387 m 359.18 40.387 l S Q
0.819709 w
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
21.16 16.996 41.324 14.031 re S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end
%%EOF

and this .eps_tex file
%% Creator: Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25), www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'test2.eps' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
}%
\providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
}%
\providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
\newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
\newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
\ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{373.18999523bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
    \relax%
    \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
\else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
\fi%
\global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
\global\let\svgscale\undefined%
\makeatother%
\begin{picture}(1,0.19934464)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{test2.eps}}%
    \put(0.11206526,0.17791435){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%
    \put(0.93654388,0.0003886){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%

and rendering as

in latex, whereas the actual .svg looks like this:


If you cross post at several sites (like reddit), please link to them and mention it. Not to waste other's time.

I recommend usage of package svg:
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-example.svg}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
width="14cm"
height="3cm"
viewBox="0 0 139.99999 30"
version="1.1"
id="svg1"
inkscape:version="1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25)"
sodipodi:docname="test.svg"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<sodipodi:namedview
    id="namedview1"
    pagecolor="#ffffff"
    bordercolor="#000000"
    borderopacity="0.25"
    inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
    inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
    inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
    inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
    inkscape:document-units="mm"
    inkscape:zoom="1.8958319"
    inkscape:cx="122.37372"
    inkscape:cy="77.538521"
    inkscape:window-width="1392"
    inkscape:window-height="1027"
    inkscape:window-x="1998"
    inkscape:window-y="25"
    inkscape:window-maximized="0"
    inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
<defs
    id="defs1" />
<g
    inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
    inkscape:groupmode="layer"
    id="layer1">
    <path
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    d="M 3.9473682,15 H 130.65789"
    id="path1" />
    <rect
    style="fill:none;fill-opacity:0.494118;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.289175;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    id="rect1"
    width="14.578605"
    height="4.9489274"
    x="11.41181"
    y="6.7481618" />
    <text
    xml:space="preserve"
    style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:3.88056px;font-family:sans-serif;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;text-align:center;letter-spacing:0px;text-anchor:middle;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.353483;paint-order:stroke markers fill"
    x="18.701111"
    y="3.5731616"
    id="text1"><tspan
        sodipodi:role="line"
        id="tspan1"
        style="stroke-width:0.353483;-inkscape-font-specification:'sans-serif, Normal';font-family:sans-serif;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-variant:normal;font-size:3.88055993px;font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;stroke:none;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1"
        x="18.701111"
        y="3.5731616">Test text</tspan></text>
</g>
</svg>
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\includesvg{\jobname-example.svg}}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Note, that you need to enable shell-escape, e.g., using pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex to compile.
Additional note: I've use the filecontens* environment only to have a single file as minimal working example. If you already have the external file, you can remove the filecontents* environment. It is not part of the solution.
To move the text position in an already generates eps_tex file, search for the \put command that places the text and change the coordinates, e.g., in your example, replace
    \put(0.13357937,0.18876313){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%

by something like
    \put(0.12,0.08876313){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%

to get

So reduce the size of the picture, change the width and/or height value of the picture environment, e.g., replace
\begin{picture}(1,0.21428571)%

by
\begin{picture}(1,0.12)%

to get

For more information about the picture environment see a LaTeX introduction.
BTW: If I convert your SVG file using inkscape test.svg -D --export-latex --export-filename=test.eps, I get:
%% Creator: Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20ef0f, 2023-11-25), www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'test-example_svg-tex.eps' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \newcommand*\fsize{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}%
  \newcommand*\lineheight[1]{\fontsize{\fsize}{#1\fsize}\selectfont}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{359.17942618bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.11334825)%
    \lineheight{1}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{test.eps}}%
    \put(0.1164366,0.0915755){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[t]{\lineheight{1.25}\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c}Test text\end{tabular}}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%

and:
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.18.2 (https://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Fri Sep 13 15:18:00 2024
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 360 25
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
/Q { grestore } bind def
/cm { 6 array astore concat } bind def
/w { setlinewidth } bind def
/J { setlinecap } bind def
/j { setlinejoin } bind def
/M { setmiterlimit } bind def
/d { setdash } bind def
/m { moveto } bind def
/l { lineto } bind def
/c { curveto } bind def
/h { closepath } bind def
/re { exch dup neg 3 1 roll 5 3 roll moveto 0 rlineto
      0 exch rlineto 0 rlineto closepath } bind def
/S { stroke } bind def
/f { fill } bind def
/f* { eofill } bind def
/n { newpath } bind def
/W { clip } bind def
/W* { eoclip } bind def
/BT { } bind def
/ET { } bind def
/BDC { mark 3 1 roll /BDC pdfmark } bind def
/EMC { mark /EMC pdfmark } bind def
/cairo_store_point { /cairo_point_y exch def /cairo_point_x exch def } def
/Tj { show currentpoint cairo_store_point } bind def
/TJ {
  {
    dup
    type /stringtype eq
    { show } { -0.001 mul 0 cairo_font_matrix dtransform rmoveto } ifelse
  } forall
  currentpoint cairo_store_point
} bind def
/cairo_selectfont { cairo_font_matrix aload pop pop pop 0 0 6 array astore
    cairo_font exch selectfont cairo_point_x cairo_point_y moveto } bind def
/Tf { pop /cairo_font exch def /cairo_font_matrix where
      { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Td { matrix translate cairo_font_matrix matrix concatmatrix dup
      /cairo_font_matrix exch def dup 4 get exch 5 get cairo_store_point
      /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Tm { 2 copy 8 2 roll 6 array astore /cairo_font_matrix exch def
      cairo_store_point /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/g { setgray } bind def
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
/d1 { setcachedevice } bind def
/cairo_data_source {
  CairoDataIndex CairoData length lt
    { CairoData CairoDataIndex get /CairoDataIndex CairoDataIndex 1 add def }
    { () } ifelse
} def
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 360 25
%%EndPageSetup
q 0 0 360 25 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 41 cm q
0 g
1.001999 w
0 J
0 j
[] 0.0 d
4 M q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
0 40.211 m 359.18 40.211 l S Q
0.819709 w
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm
21.16 16.82 41.324 14.027 re S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end
%%EOF

And using these files results in:

So it seems, the export is broken on your side. But this is more an Inkscape issue than a TeX issue.

That's a good approach for the svg, but I have a few other eps-eps_tex figures whose source code I don't have and they have the same issue. With this I can at least include some, but it does not fix the underlying issue...

@HerpDerpington You explicitly asked for Inkscape SVG files in your question and only shown a SVG file but none eps_tex file and the corresponding eps file. Without knowing at least one of your problematic files: The eps_tex files are usually files with a picture environment and \put commands to place text and \includegraphics command(s) for the eps image. So you can change the coordinates to move text.

I have updated the question, now all files are there. Originally, I forgot to wrote that to reproduce this the image has to be exported from Inkscape as written.

@HerpDerpington I've updated to show, how to change an existing eps_tex file.

@HerpDerpington I've also updated to show the eps_tex file I get with your SVG file.

Which eps did you use for my eps_tex? I think I might have found the issue, which seems to be incorrect dimension stored in the eps, as you have noticed. The eps_tex itself seems to be correct at first glance

@HerpDerpington The one I've exported using Inkscape.

Which Inkscape version and which OS did you use? The cairo version differs for both eps samples

@HerpDerpington As shown at the begin of the eps_tex file: Inkscape 1.3.2 (091e20ef0f, 2023-11-25). OS is openSUSE Linux Tumbleweed. cairo 1.18.2 is IMHO the current version → https://cairographics.org/

The issue is caused by the %%BoundingBox for me it is offset and in your case it starts with 0 0.

I have the same behavior as in my question with cairo 1.18.2. The inkscape build is the same as yours. Then I don't see where the export bug comes from.

@HerpDerpington Have you exported the page or the drawing (Inkscape option -C or -D)? I use inkscape "test.svg" -D --export-latex --export-filename="test.eps".

I used the GUI, which seems to be the same as -C. Using -D, I get the same as you, which seems to be some progress. Unfortunately, I have discovered at least one more example where this does not work. I will try to construct a minimal example.

I found a new example and updated the question.

@HerpDerpington Sorry, I've already adapted my answer to an adapted question before. I'm not willing to do this again and again. If you have a follow-up question, please ask a new one. BTW: The export dialog in the GUI also provides four tabs for different kinds of export. And I've also told how to do the export using the CLI. And I've told how to use package svg to do it automatically. And I've told, that how to use inkscape is not really a (La)TeX question. And … I'm finished with this question. Maybe I'll delete this answer, if it is not longer valid for the multiply changed question.
